# How to create scrollbar in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic3

I have a chart using the Highcharts library, my chart looks like this:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands

However, the X-axis is composed of dates and has no limits. I’d like to know how to put a horizontal scrollbar (on the X-axis)?

I use Ionic 3. I tried to use highstock, but I didn't succeed. Could someone help me? I’d like to see an code sample using highstock, thank you.

Comment: What was the issue with highstock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you're talking about is called the navigator & exists only in highstock. The navigator is enabled by default for the first series in all Highstock charts.
To use highstock in Angular or Ionic use this in your ts file or page:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
```

Here's a small example of how the navigator looks like:

```js
var seriesOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];

/**
 * Create the chart when all data is loaded
 */
function createChart() {

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} USD</b><br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

$.each(names, function (i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json',    function (data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data
        };

        // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
        // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,you helped me a lot! Your material helped me a lot and I also used this documentation:

https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to use a horizontal scrollbar in highcharts is by using navigator and scrollar:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/navigator

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/scrollbar

But based on the above doc, it is only available for highstock. So I would try to make that work. (I have used it successfully)

There is also [zoom and pan](http://jsfiddle.net/74st0pgh/1/), but I doubt that's what you want.

```
zoomType: 'x',
panning: true,
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `require('highcharts/highmaps')` instead of `require('highcharts')` in imports

```
@NgModule({
    ...
   imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
     ChartModule.forRoot( 
      require('highcharts/highmaps')
      ],
})
```